# 鉛 Reading Phonology

Tags: etymology, topolect, phonology

Why does this word for Lead 鉛 seem to have two different pronounciations?

In most Chinese Languages / Languages that borrowed this word ( Japanese / Korean ) they all read similar to the Middle Chinese reading ywen .

Examples: Xiang (Yenn) Hokkien (Yân/Iân) Cantonese (Yun⁴/Jyun⁴) Japanese Go-on (En) Korean ( Yon/Yeon/연 )

But in some languages they seem to read like a word with a K- sound

Examples: Mandarian ( Qian ) Gan ( Kan ) Jin ( Qie ) Wu ( Khe )

Is this the result of a sound change from Y to Ki? Or just the form of a different reading? I appreciate any answers to my question!

Comment: Note that those modern varieties that preserve the -m/-n distinction (e.g. Cantonese, Hakka, Hokkien, Teochew) retain the null initial for both (Standard Canto.: 鹽 jim4 vs 鉛 jyun4); many have a distinction in the vowel (Jian'ou variety of Min Bei: 鹽 îng vs 鉛 ṳ̂ing), and then you have coastal Min varieties where 鹽 derives from a different reflex of Old Chinese through a proto-Min initial *z- (Fuzhou Min Dong: 鹽 vernacular - sièng; literary - ièng; 鉛 - iòng).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bu (2018, p. 75-76)](https://digitalcommons.oberlin.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1145&context=honors) contests that changed to avoid confusion among minerals:

> These two characters are excellent examples of phono-semantic dissimilation because each has an potentially ambiguous homophonic counterpart: 鹽 (“salt”) and 炎 (“inflammation”). Coincidentally the four were once all pronounced [iɛnT2] in most
> Mandarin dialects: 鉛 (lead), as a part of the 沿 phonological series, lost its -/w/- glide due to lexical diffusion among the series, so it turned out to be pronounced the same with 鹽 (salt). This caused a severe problem of two important minerals being homophonic and indistinguishable in conversations, so the pronunciation of 鉛 was
> changed to [͡tɕʰiɛn], which is a palpably abrupt development since the fortis consonant[͡tɕʰ] cannot be derived from any phonemes in */jʷiɛn/. With the expansion to more
> southern varieties having the same change (W-SZ and GA-NC), now the initial is [kʰ],
> which only corresponds to MC 溪 */kʰ/ in W-SZ. Thus, the conclusion should be a
> character with the rough pronunciation of [kʰ] + (-/j/- glide) + front vowel + nasal
> substituted the original 鉛, a process called 訓讀 (morpheme substitution of the
> same character, comparative to Japanese kun’yomi) – the new morpheme inherits all the old semantic sets entailed by the character 鉛, while the pronunciation took a
> sudden and drastic shift to a completely irrelevant one. Hirayama (1998: 198) states
> that [kʰam] is a morpheme meaning “白鐵皮 (lit. white iron skin, roughly slices of
> white metal)” in Lichuan dialect of Gan, proposing that to be the substitute that has
> gone through sound changes when it was spread into other varieties. Valid or not, the
> fact that this morpheme with [kh
> ] initial does not share a common etymological root
> with the original 鉛, therefore it was a dissimilative gesture to eliminate potential
> confusion.

---

His work seems to be based off of that of Hisao Hirayama (平山久雄) who wrote a paper entitled:《普通话“铅”字读音的来源》:

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

Comment: This is so interesting! It seems like this is quite a possible case that happened to the original word

Answer (score -1):

In some dialects, zcs and gkh became jqx during Ming Dynasty. The other dialects kept their original pronunciation.